# UTF-8 Unicode characters in MySQL 5.7 vs MySQL 8

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

We recently went through a migration from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8. On MySQL 5.7 we simply added the "useUnicode=true" in the connection string to get unicode characters functional. On MySQL 8 we keep on running into exceptions due to unicode characters. We are using Java for the back end.
Example:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x80\xC2\x99t ...' for column 'subject' at row 1
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing any `useUnicode` setting in MySQL. According to very quick Google search, that can be a JDBC thing. Are you using Java?

Comment: Yes we are using Java for the back end

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1` results, either for an actual table or for a small [mcve] table that can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the query given below, it will update the support for Unicode. It used to work with earlier versions of MySQL, I am not sure about MySQL 8.

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Also check `character-set-server = utf8mb4` in my.cnf and `useUnicode=true` in your JDBC connection.